# How to add telerik web report designer control in ASP.NET web form application?

Tags: asp.net, web, telerik, report

I have an ASP.NET web form application, I want to add telerik web report designer control there, is there a sample code or helpful link there for this? All the articles I saw so far are related to ASP.NET Core or ASP.NET MVC applications.

Regards,

Zain

Comment: There is a nice blog post on the matter: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/embedding-beautiful-reporting-asp-dotnet-web-forms-applications. Check out the documentation too - https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/asp-net-report-viewer-embedding.

Comment: https://www.telerik.com/forums/web-report-designer-control-in-asp-net-web-form-application  please follow the demo application sent on this page from the telerik team member.